# Executing series of Erlang functions with error forwarding

Tags: erlang

I would like to execute series of functions that can return the same values (`ok` or `{error, SomeError}`) and forward error up if any of them fails. I know how to achieve that with many nested case-of statements as shown below.

```
case fun1 of
  ok ->
    case fun2 of
      ok ->
        ...;
      {error, Error} ->
        {error, Error};
  {error, Error} ->
    {error, Error}
end.
```

Is there any other way how to do that more elegantly like for example it can be done in Rust language with Result forwarding?

Comment: In the Elixir language you can do that with the [`with`](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/mix-otp/docs-tests-and-with.html#with) statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why you dont use `try..catch` like below:
// Edit: it seems that the `{error, Error}` come from `erlang:error/1`. It isn't successful pattern, so I change code little bit.

```
test()->
    try
        func1(),
        func2()
    of
        ok -> do_any_thing()
    catch
        error:Error -> {error, Error)
    end.
```